# Asynchronous I/O in C with a callback function -- exactly when and how does I/O thread return?

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, io

My question is about exactly when the I/O thread in an asynchronous I/O call returns when a call back function is involved.  Specifically, given this very general code for reading a file ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<aio.h>

...

// callback function:
void finish_aio(sigval_t sigval) {

/* do stuff ... maybe close the file */

}

int main() {

    struct aiocb my_aiocb;
    int aio_return;
...
//Open file, take care of any other prelims, then
//Fill in file-specific info for my_aiocb, then
//Fill in callback information for my_aiocb:
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = finish_aio;
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &info_on_file;

// then read the file:
    aio_return = aio_read(&my_aiocb);
    
// do stuff that doesn't need data that is being read ...
// then block execution until read is complete:
    while(aio_error(&my_aiocb) == EINPROGRESS) {}
// etc.
}
```

I understand that the callback function is called as soon as the read of the file is completed.  But what exactly happens then?  Does the I/O thread start running the callback `finish_aio()`?  Or does it spawn a new thread to handle that callback, while it returns to the main thread?  Another way to put this would be: When does `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` stop returning `EINPROGRESS`?  Is it just before the call to the callback, or when the callback is completed?

Comment: Which OS? Linux? If you need asynchronous I/O I highly recommend epoll instead. man aio: "The current Linux POSIX AIO implementation is provided in user space by glibc. This has a number of limitations, most notably that maintaining multiple threads to perform I/O operations is expensive and scales poorly."

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that the callback function is called as soon as the read of the file is completed. But what exactly happens then?

What happens is that when the IO finishes it "behaves as if" it started a new thread (similar to calling `pthread_create(&ignored, NULL, finish_aio, &info_on_file)`).

> When does `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` stop returning `EINPROGRESS`?

I'd expect that `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` stops returning `EINPROGRESS` as soon as the IO finishes, then the system (probably the standard library) either begins creating a new thread to call `finish_aio()` or "unblocks" a "previously created without you knowing" thread. However, I don't think the exact order is documented anywhere ("implementation defined") because it doesn't make much sense to call `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` from anywhere other than the `finish_aio()` anyway.

More specifically; if you're using polling (`my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE`) then you'd repeatedly check `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` yourself and you can't care if you're notified before or after this happens because you're not notified at all; and if you aren't using polling you'd wait until you are notified (via. a new thread or a signal) that there's a reason to check `aio_error(&my_aiocb)`.

In other words, your `finish_aio()` would look more like this:

```
void finish_aio(sigval_t sigval) {
    struct aiocb * my_aiocb = (struct aiocb *)sigval;
    int status;

    status = aio_error(&my_aiocb);

    /* Figure out what to do (handle the error or handle the file's data) */
```

.. and for `main()` the `while(aio_error(&my_aiocb) == EINPROGRESS)` (which may waste a huge amount of CPU time for nothing) would be deleted and/or possibly replaced with something else (e.g. a `pthread_cond_wait()` to wait until the code in `finish_aio()` does a `pthread_cond_signal()` to tell the main thread it can continue).

---

To understand this, let's take a look at what pure polling would look like:

```
int main() {

    struct aiocb my_aiocb;
    int aio_return;
    ...
    //Open file, take care of any other prelims, then
    //Fill in file-specific info for my_aiocb, then

    my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE;   /* CHANGED! */
    // my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = finish_aio;
    // my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
    // my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &info_on_file;

    // then read the file:
    aio_return = aio_read(&my_aiocb);

    // do stuff that doesn't need data that is being read ...
    // then block execution until read is complete:
    while(aio_error(&my_aiocb) == EINPROGRESS) {}
    finish_aio(sigval_t sigval);           /* ADDED! */
}
```

In this case it behaves almost the same as your original code, except that there's no extra thread (and you can't care if the "thread that doesn't exist" is started before or after `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` returns a value other than `EINPROGRESS`).

The problem with pure polling is that the `while(aio_error(&my_aiocb) == EINPROGRESS)` could waste a huge amount of CPU time constantly checking when nothing has happened yet.

The main purpose of using `my_aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD` is to avoid wasting a possibly huge amount of CPU time polling when nothing changed (not forgetting that in some cases wasting CPU time polling like this can prevent other threads, including the `finish_aio()` thread, from getting CPU time). In other words, you want to delete the `while(aio_error(&my_aiocb) == EINPROGRESS)` loop, so **you used `SIGEV_THREAD` so that you can delete that polling loop**.

The new problem is that (if the main thread has to wait until the data is ready) you need some other way for the main thread to wait until the data is ready. However, typically it's not "the `aio_read()` completed" that you actually care about, it's something else. For example, maybe the raw file data is a bunch of values in a text file (like "12, 34, 56, 78") and you want to parse that data and create an array of integers, and want to notify the main thread that the array of integers is ready (and don't want to notify the main thread if you're starting to parse the file's data). It might be like:

```
int parsed_file_result = 0;

void finish_aio(sigval_t sigval) {
    struct aiocb * my_aiocb = (struct aiocb *)sigval;
    int status;

    status = aio_error(&my_aiocb);
    close(my_aiocb->aio_fildes);
    if(status == 0) {
        /* Read was successful */
        parsed_file_result = parse_file_data(); /* Create the array of integers */
        
    } else {
        /* Read failed, handle the error somehow */

        parsed_file_result = -1;  /* Tell main thread we failed to create the array of integers */
    }
    /* Tell the main thread it can continue somehow */
}
```

One of the best ways to tell the main thread it can continue (at the end of `finish_aio()`) is to use pthread conditional variables (e.g. `pthread_cond_signal()` called at the end of `finish_aio()`; with `pthread_cond_wait()` in the main thread). In this case the main thread will simply block (the kernel/scheduler will not give it any CPU time until `pthread_cond_signal()` is called) so it wastes no CPU time polling.

Sadly, pthread conditional variables aren't trivial (they require a mutex, initialization, etc), and teaching/showing their use here is a little too far from the original topic. Fortunately; you shouldn't have much trouble finding a good tutorial elsewhere.

The important part is that if you used `SIGEV_THREAD` (so that you can delete that awful `while(aio_error(&my_aiocb) == EINPROGRESS)` polling loop) you're left with no reason to call `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` until after the `finish_aio()` has already been started; and no reason to care if `aio_error(&my_aiocb)` would've been changed (or not) before `finish_aio()` is started.